# apache camel spring dsl check if body contains string

Tags: apache-camel, spring-dsl

I am trying to check :

```
<simple>${body} contains 'verification'</simple>
```

Body is the json:

```
{"verification": {"email": "bb@wp.pl", "code": "1234"}}
```

But this condition doesn't work. I've tried as well:

```
<simple>${body} contains &#39;verification&#39;</simple>
<simple>${bodyAs(String)} contains 'verification'</simple>
<simple>${body.verification} != null</simple>
```

Could you please suggest me something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this case:

```
<simple>${bodyAs(String)} contains 'verification'</simple>
```

didn't work cause:
[In Camel the message body can be of any types. Some types are safely readable multiple times, and therefore do not 'suffer' from becoming 'empty'.](http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html)

[It fixes by Stream caching](http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html)

Comment: and body().convertTo(String.class) in Java

Answer (score 5):

I guess the body is maybe not a String, then try with

```
<simple>${bodyAs(String)} contains 'verification'</simple>
```

And btw what version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Hi, Claus. I've mentioned this approach - it doesn't work for me. I use 2.10.0 version of camel